# rvalue reference for istringstream not working

Tags: c++, stl

This works:

```
string S;
istringstream iss(S);
vector<string> V{ istream_iterator<string>{iss}, istream_iterator<string>{} };
```

But why does this not work? Please explain in detail.

```
string S;
vector<string> V{ istream_iterator<string>{istringstream(S)}, istream_iterator<string>{} };
```

Comment: The [constructor of `istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator) receives the stream by lvalue reference.

Comment: Ah, I see. I desperately wanted a one line code for that.

Comment: It's not working for me on VS 2017.